# Cannot access monit web interface

Tags: monitoring, monit

I just installed Monit on my server. I want to access to the web interface to manage it but the web is not accessible.

The machine is an instance in AWS, the port is open. I have tried many configurations:

```
set httpd port 2812
    use address localhost  
    allow localhost        
    allow admin:monit  

set httpd port 2812
    use address [instance-public-ip]  
    allow [instance-public-ip]        
    allow admin:monit

set httpd port 2812
    use address [instance-private-ip]  
    allow [instance-private-ip]        
    allow admin:monit
```

Not working with any of the above. If I do monit status with the internal IP, the output is:

> System 'ip-172-[...]'   status                       OK
> monitoring status            Monitored   monitoring mode
> active   on reboot                    start   load average
> [0.00] [0.00] [0.00]   cpu                          0.5%us 0.4%sy
> 0.0%wa   memory usage                 143.1 MB [14.6%]   swap usage                   0 B [0.0%]   uptime                       1d 23h 25m   boot time
> Thu, 11 Jun 2020 10:59:14   data collected               Sat, 13 Jun
> 2020 10:24:17

I know I must be doing something wrong or missing something. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration denies access by IP address to everyone except, apparently, the IP addresses of your instance itself. If you intend to connect from a different IP address, you also need to `allow` it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
set httpd port 2812 and
use address 0.0.0.0 
allow 0.0.0.0/0 
allow admin:password
```